# datetimepicker only works in rows above the previous row selected in multi update form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datetimepicker

I am a newbie and this is my first database project, so apologies for any basic errors.

I have a Multi Update Form, when i select a row, i am able to select a date from datetimepicker in that row and any row  above the next one i also select. however the datetimepicker does not work in any row below the last row i select. hope that makes sense,  eg if i select row 10 it works, if i then also select row 5 (before submitting) it works, but if i now also select row 6 it wont work, but will work if i also select row 3 which is lower than 5 - any ideas? Thanks

Code Im using

````
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Update Multiple Mysql Data using Checkbox with Ajax in PHP</title>
  

<!-- Minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Minified JS library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Minified Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container">  
            <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h3 align="center">Update Multiple Mysql Data using Checkbox with Ajax in PHP</h3><br />
    <form method="post" id="update_form">
                    <div align="left">
                        <input type="submit" name="multiple_update" id="multiple_update" class="btn btn-info" value="Multiple Update" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <th width="5%"></th>
                                <th width="25%">Date</th>
                                <th width="30%">Duty Type</th>
                                <th width="20%">Duty Start</th>
                                <th width="20%">Duty Stop</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>  


<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    
    function fetch_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"select.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                var html = '';
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].tdId+'" data-tddate="'+data[count].tdDate+'" data-dutytype="'+data[count].dutyType+'" data-dutystart="'+data[count].dutyStart+'" data-dutystop="'+data[count].dutyStop+'" class="check_box"  /></td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].tdDate+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].dutyType+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].dutyStart+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].dutyStop+'</td>';
                  }
                $('tbody').html(html);

                 
                
            }
        });
    }

    fetch_data();

    $(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
        var html = '';
        if(this.checked)

        // below is used for the dropdown on duty type - include dropdown database connection then refers dutytype
        <?php
        include('dropdown.php');
        ?>
        
        {
            html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-tddate="'+$(this).data('tddate')+'" data-dutytype="'+$(this).data('dutytype')+'" data-dutystart="'+$(this).data('dutystart')+'" data-dutystop="'+$(this).data('dutystop')+'" class="check_box" checked /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="tddate[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("tddate")+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td><select name="dutytype[]" id="dutytype_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="form-control"><option></option><?php foreach ($results as $output) {?><option><?php echo$output["dutyType"];?></option><?php }?></select></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="dutystart[]" class="form-control" id="dstart_time" value="'+$(this).data("dutystart")+'" readonly/></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="dutystop[]" class="form-control" id="dstop_time" value="'+$(this).data("dutystop")+'" readonly /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" /></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-tddate="'+$(this).data('tddate')+'" data-dutytype="'+$(this).data('dutytype')+'" data-dutystart="'+$(this).data('dutystart')+'" data-dutystop="'+$(this).data('dutystop')+'" class="check_box" /></td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('tddate')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('dutytype')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('dutystart')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('dutystop')+'</td>';
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').html(html);
        $('#dutytype_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('dutytype'));
        // this is where you put the datetimepicker  stuffs :-)
        $('#dstart_time').datetimepicker({ clearBtn: true, weekStart: 1, pickDate: false, todayBtn:  1, autoclose: 1, todayHighlight: 1, startView: 1, minView: 0, maxView: 1, forceParse: 0, minuteStep: 15 });
        $('#dstop_time').datetimepicker({ clearBtn: true, weekStart: 1, pickDate: false, todayBtn:  1, autoclose: 1, todayHighlight: 1, startView: 1, minView: 0, maxView: 1, forceParse: 0, minuteStep: 15 });
        
    });


        

    $('#update_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('.check_box:checked').length > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"multiple_update.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function()
                {
                    alert('Data Updated');
                    fetch_data();
                }
            })
        }
    });

});  
</script>

<!-- datetimepicker files -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved the problem, In the html input line I changed the class on the 2 lines from form-control to "Datepicker-needed" then lower down i used the class as a link and not the name so changed  $('#dstart_time').datetimepicker to $('.Datepicker-needed').datetimepicker etc and it now works